# Retrieve only a portion of a string

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve only the first part of a VARCHAR(15) string. Which string operation is fastest? My data is like this:

```
80:0:0:0
100:00:00:00
0:00:25:60
```

I'd like the results to be:

```
80
100
0
```

Comment: What about the case where no `:` is present?

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @str TABLE(x VARCHAR(15));

INSERT @str VALUES ('80:0:0:0'), ('100:00:00:00'), ('0:00:25:60');

SELECT FirstPart = SUBSTRING(x, 1, CHARINDEX(':', x)-1) FROM @str;
```

Results:

```
FirstPart
---------
80
100
0
```

If you need to show the whole string even if it doesn't contain `:` then you can do this instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(x, 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(':', x), 0), 15)) FROM @str;
```

Comment: thank u i got it like this SELECT LEFT(@FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', @FullName) - 1) AS [FirstName]

Comment: @SuribabuKandukuri Yes, you can use LEFT as well. There is no performance difference here.